# Classes contains field of the other class issue

Tags: c++, oop

I`m trying to create an example of 2 classes that each class contain a field of the other class, for example(header file):

```
class Sentence{

private:
     int wordNum;
     Word words[200];
public:..
};

class Word{

private:
        char *word;
        Sentence  sentences[100];
public:..
}
```

when I`m doing that Word Words[200] not defined, how the order of the class need to be that both of classes will be defined? because it affect on the public methodes.
I would like to get some advice what to do, Thanks!

Comment: Think about this again. It's like `struct X { X x; }`. In other words, what's the content of a box that contains itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: The only way to "fix" this is to rethink your hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Both of your classes are contained inside each other, which is nonsense.

What you probably want is to hold pointers to each other. That is:

```
class Sentence
    ...
    Word* words[200];
    ...
};

class Word {
    ...
    Sentence* sentences[100];
    ...
};
```

Comment: It compiles but it introduces a bunch of problems along with memory handling. I don't want to offend anyone but I think that's not a good piece of advice here.

Comment: We don't know anything else about the problem other than "I tried this, it didn't compile". I can go ahead and point out that your proposed answer is logically flawed, as your vector will hold copies of the objects instead of referencing, which could be what was intended. No point in being pedantic over something that was not even specified nor asked.

Comment: Neither did I downvote your answer, nor is may remark _pedantic_ or offensive. Along with the question, the OP "_specified_" that he's presumably a beginner. Stop complaining please! Enabling relationality in my example is a matter of introducing a single `*` (or a shared_ptr or whatever there may fit)... Tidy handling of a combination of arrays and pointers is hard to achieve. Even if a certain solution may be the one "requested" by the OP there's no point in NOT giving a hint towards possible problems of it. (There's a chance that this is the best fit but imho it's unlikely.)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. A `Sentence` must contain 200 instances of `Word`, and therefore 20,000 instances of `Sentence`; just try to calculate its size.

A `Sentence` can contain a `Sentence*`, or a `vector<Sentence>`, or any number of other things that lead to other `Sentences`, but not an array of `Sentences`. You must revise your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. Think about it - what would the size in bytes of `Sentence` instance be? Clearly, it must be at least 200 times the size of `Word`. Then what should the size of `Word` be? At least 100 times the size of `Sentence`. So `sizeof(Sentence) > sizeof(Word) > sizeof(Sentence)`. Can you see what's wrong with this picture?

You can have `Sentence` hold a `Word*` or `vector<Word>`, or have `Word` hold `Sentence*` or `vector<Sentence>`, or both. Once you do that, then forward declarations, as suggested by @McGarnagle, would work.

Answer (score -1):

Let's imagine this would compile.

You `Word` has 100 `sentences` where each `Sentence` has 200 `words` (20000 `Word`s here), each of which has 100 `sentences` (2000000 `Sentence`s here), each of which has 200 `words` (400000000 `Words`), each of which ...

I think I may stop here. You'll probably realize that this is not what you wanted to have.

You need to think again about your structure and you should take into account what a user or maintainer of such code would probably expect.

A sentence that contains several words -> Well ok that's logical.
A word that contains sentences? -> Why should a word ever *contain* sentences? Noone will ever expect this to be the case.

Furthermore: If you don't have a project that handles only sentences that *always* contain *exactly* 200 Words you may well consider using a dynamic memory structure like `std::vector`.

```
class Sentence
{
private:
   int wordNum;
   std::vector<Word> words;
public:
   ...
};
```

---

If relationality is required you're of course free to use pointers.

If you want some kind of automated lifetime (if you have C++11 capability at hand) you could for example use a vector of `std::shared_ptr` from sentences to words. -> Each sentences containing a specific word has its own shared ptr to that word object. If all sentences with a specific word go out of scope / are destroyed, the word will be removed, too.

I'd still recommend to stick to something that enables you to make use of RAII.

Comment: A word might be holding references to sentences that share it; in that case, having sentences holding their own words is wrong, as they are not sharing words. See, I can be pedantic too.

Comment: I guess the OP probably knows better (than you) about the relationality of what he wants to achieve and his example had sentences that HOLD their words so I didn't diverge my solution from it. But yes it may still not be what OP inteded to do.